# Extension installed but nothing happened

Tags: shoutem

I wanted to change and add some text to the login screen of my app so I went into the shoutem.auth and edited the LoginScreen.js file. I then pushed and installed my extension with no issues but when I went to run my app, no changes were made. First time messing with react so not sure if I'm missing something. Just edited both placeholder texts and added a Caption tag:

```
renderLoginComponent() {
    const { settings } = this.props;
    const { username } = this.state;

    let components = null;
    if (settings.providers.email.enabled) {
      components = (
        <View>
        <Caption styleName="h-center lg-gutter-vertical">
          To login: Username is your last name (all lowercase) along with your book number. No spaces. See example below for this.
          Password is your Book Number.
        </Caption>
          <Divider />
          <Divider styleName="line" />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Last Name & Book # (e.g. smith1234567)"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="email-address"
            keyboardAppearance="dark"
            onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
            returnKeyType="done"
            value={username}
          />
          <Divider styleName="line" />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password is your Book # (e.g. 1234567)"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardAppearance="dark"
            secureTextEntry
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
            returnKeyType="done"
          />
          <Divider styleName="line" />
          <Divider />
          <Button
            styleName="full-width inflexible"
            onPress={this.performLogin}
          >
            <Text>LOG IN</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return components;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you're using your own authentication extension and not Shoutem's authentication extension?

After pushing and installing, you now have `shoutem.auth` and `yourDevname.auth` in the app. Can you check if you're using yours or the Shoutem one?

Comment: I followed the documentation for 'Directly Modify the Extension Code' here: https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions so I am using the Shoutem one

Comment: You should utilize your own extension, because what you do with `Directly Modify the Extension Code` is that you make a brand new extension. That's the one you should use in the Builder. Let me know if that works.